# Inserting custom metadata

Tags: custom-object, rest, metadata, custom

I'm using REST api towards Salesforce for inserting various kinds of data from our other systems. And for data that is regarded as configuration (in this case a list of freight forwarders) we have created a custom metadata object Carrier__mdt).

So now I have created a script to populate this object. And it's not working:

```
    message: 'entity type cannot be inserted: Carrier',
    errorCode: 'CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY',
```

I have tried giving every kind of access right to the object and it's field, but no go.I'm doing a POST request on the object URL

https://XXXX/v51.0/sobjects/Carrier__mdt

I've seen other people ask this question before, and been given every kind of answer from "that is not possible" to "it works now". Can it be done?

Comment: You have to do this via the Metadata API.

Comment: you could write an apex rest service that exploits [Custom Metadata Services](https://andyinthecloud.com/2017/08/29/introducing-custom-metadata-services/)

Answer (score 0):

Custom metadata is considered as metadata due to which the DML Operations cannot be performed on Custom Metadata Type. Each change triggering a record creation is treated as a deployment.

Please refer below link for more details.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Metadata_Operations.htm#apex_class_Metadata_Operations